# Parsing a json object with child elements goes wrong

Tags: javascript

I am `fetch`ing data from server and I'm receiving following response:

```
{"Sections[0].Title":"SectionsTitleText","Title":"TitleText"}
```

I want it to become an object like this:

```
{Sections: [{Title:"SectionTitleText"}], Title: "TitleText"}
```

but instead I have this:

```
{Sections[0].Title: "SectionsTitleText","Title":"TitleText"}
```

where `Sections[0].Title` is a single property name, not an array of objects. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem; is the server sending the data in a wrong format or do you actually want to change the received object?

Comment: @Randy I cant affect how data is sent, so my goal is to parse this object in such a way that `Sections[0].Title` is treated as an array, not as a property name.

Comment: How did you get to the third example? Because that isnt valid in JS or JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function for spliting the path to the value and generate new objects or arrays for it.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var way = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.'),
        last = way.pop();

    way.reduce(function (o, k, i, kk) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {});
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var obj = { 'Sections[0].Title': 'SectionsTitleText', Title: 'TitleText' };

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
    var value = obj[key];
    delete obj[key];
    setValue(obj, key, value);
});

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` is working correctly and is not in fact going wrong.  your JSON string says to create a Javascript object with a field in it named `Sections[0].Title`; if you don't want to do that, then you can't use `JSON.parse` (which is what `jQuery.ajax()` or `axios()` or whatever will use under the hood unless you specify otherwise).

Since you don't mention what transport library you're using in your code, we can only guess at what specifically will help you.  But if you're using `jQuery.ajax()`, try setting a different [converter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for `text/json`.  If you're using axios, try specifying `transformRequest` in your [request object](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config).

Comment: I am using vanilla `fetch`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can parse the JSON to Javascript using the `JSON.parse` method
2. Then use the array `map` method to map the array as required.

Comment: This would not work, the key and array index are combined as a key if you parse the object.

Comment: The logic for separation and new Key needs to be in `map` function.